# VBA to VBS - iframe permission denied

Tags: html, vba, iframe, web-scraping, vbscript

I recently wrote an Excel VBA script to login and navigate an intranet site to download a CSV report. It contains some links and buttons that I need to click inside an iframe. It took some effort to figure out the iframe stuff, but it works. I still don't know how to click "Save" without the download file dialog box being the active window, but that's for another day.

I'm in the process of converting this script to VBS and have run into this error message:

[image]

Here are the relevant code snippets:

**VBA Code (this works)**

```
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
...
Dim iframeDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set iframeDoc = ie.document.frames("fmReports").document
' select the custom report
iframeDoc.getElementById("tvCustomReport").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
' run the report
iframeDoc.getElementById("btnRunReport").Click
```

**VBS Code (this presents the error dialog above)**

```
Dim oIE
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True
...
Dim iframeDoc
Set iframeDoc = oIE.document.getElementById("fmReports").ContentWindow.Document
' select the custom report
iframeDoc.getElementById("tvCustomReport").Click
WScript.Sleep 3000 'wait here just in case
' run the report
iframeDoc.getElementById("btnRunReport").Click
```

**Questions/Thoughts**

I've turned off just about every security feature I can find in IE.

**Are these different domains? (XSS issue perhaps)**
The main intranet site url is http://192.168.0.111/app2019 while the contents of the iframe url is http://192.168.0.111/app2018.

Line 49 (referenced in the screenshot) of my full script is the second line in the VBS snippet (Set iframeDoc =...)

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you try .ContentDocument rather than .ContentWindow.Document or is that not supported in vbs?

Comment: Just tried it, and it appears to fail silently. No error dialog, but also no progress in navigating the website or additional logging messages. I have no idea how to debug that.

Comment: Please add the code that shows how `oIE` object is created.

Comment: Added it. Pretty standard stuff as far as I can tell. The script successfully logs into the website, navigates a few pages, but then dies when I try to click a link that's in the iframe. The VBA version works fine.